# How To Immediately End A Program When The Window Is Closed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to C# and have created a basic program that I'm running through Visual Studio 2010. When the window is closed, the program stops. However there's a delay of a few seconds before the IDE goes back to edit mode. How can I immediately end the program when the window is closed?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    While (Visible) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 254) {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
        }
        for (int c = 254; c >= 0) {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried removing "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);" from the loops but that still did not help fix the issue. I've also been able to reproduce this on multiple machines. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: The delay you are referring to is not uncommon.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish - why do you want to reduce the delay?

Comment: Where is this while loop executing? And why?

Comment: Your program cannot stop until the nested for() loops are completed.  You are writing dangerous code, be sure to pick up a book about winforms programming.

Comment: Thanks @Hans that helped resolved my issue. I'll also start looking for a book on winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay happens because the for loops need to finish before the while loop can check if Visible is still true. I was able to fix it by adding **&& Visible == true** to the conditional test in each for loop. That way the loop ends as soon as Visible turns false.

Answer (score 1):

When Visual Studio is debugging a program it executes the program through a proxy application.  After your program has ended the proxy also has to stop, plus visual studio has to go back to its edit mode.  This transition isn't immediate, and is likely the delay you're experiencing.

You can try builing the program in Release mode and running it without debugging.  It should be able to shut down quickly then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.Exit();
```

I doubt that there is a faster way.

Comment: From the people who brought you `ERROR_SUCCESS`: [`Environment.FailFast'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To close the running application (no matter which forms are active) you use:

```
System.Environment.Exit();
```

And you can add this to the onClose event of the form

Answer (score -1):

Just run program with <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>